# PostgreSQL text range scan

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, indexing, postgresql-9.3

I have written a query whose aim is to get 10 results including the current one, padding up to 9 entries on either side for an alphabetical list which can be sorted by the reciever.
This is the query I am using, my issue however is not with the result, *but because neither of the queries is using an index*.

```
(
  SELECT
    uid,
    title
  FROM
    books
  WHERE
  lower(title) < lower('Frankenstein')
  ORDER BY title desc
  LIMIT 9
)
UNION
(
  SELECT
    uid,
    title
  FROM
    books
  WHERE
  lower(title) >= lower('Frankenstein')
  ORDER BY title
  LIMIT 10
)
ORDER BY title;
```

The index I am trying to utilize is a simple btree, no text_pattern_ops etc as below:

`CREATE INDEX books_title_idx ON books USING btree (lower(title));`

If I run explain on the first part of the unioin, in spite of the limit and order, it performs a full table scan

```
explain analyze 
SELECT
  uid,
  title
FROM
  books
WHERE
lower(title) < lower('Frankenstein')
ORDER BY title desc
LIMIT 9
```

`Limit  (cost=69.04..69.06 rows=9 width=152) (actual time=6.276..6.292 rows=9 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=69.04..69.67 rows=251 width=152) (actual time=6.273..6.277 rows=9 loops=1)
        Sort Key: ((title))
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
        ->  Seq Scan on books  (cost=0.00..63.80 rows=251 width=152) (actual time=0.056..5.227 rows=267 loops=1)
              Filter: (lower((title)) < 'frankenstein'::text)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 486
Total runtime: 6.359 ms`

when I do an equality check on the same query - *the index is used*

```
explain analyze
SELECT
  uid,
  title
FROM
  books
WHERE
lower(title) = lower('Frankenstein')
ORDER BY title desc
```

`Sort  (cost=17.04..17.05 rows=4 width=152) (actual time=0.054..0.054 rows=0 loops=1)
  Sort Key: ((title))
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on books  (cost=4.31..17.00 rows=4 width=152) (actual time=0.041..0.041 rows=0 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: (lower((title)) = 'frankenstein'::text)
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on books_title_idx  (cost=0.00..4.31 rows=4 width=0) (actual time=0.036..0.036 rows=0 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (lower((title)) = 'frankenstein'::text)
Total runtime: 0.129 ms`

and the same applies when I do a between query

```
explain analyze
SELECT
  uid,
  title
FROM
  books
WHERE
lower(title) > lower('Frankenstein') AND lower(title) < lower('Gulliver''s Travels')
ORDER BY title
```

`Sort  (cost=17.08..17.09 rows=4 width=152) (actual time=0.511..0.529 rows=25 loops=1)
  Sort Key: (title)
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on books  (cost=4.33..17.04 rows=4 width=152) (actual time=0.118..0.213 rows=25 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: ((lower(title) > 'frankenstein'::text) AND (lower(title) < 'gulliver''s travels'::text))
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on books_title_idx  (cost=0.00..4.33 rows=4 width=0) (actual time=0.087..0.087 rows=25 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((lower(title) > 'frankenstein'::text) AND (lower(title) < 'gulliver''s travels'::text))
Total runtime: 0.621 ms`

What I am obviously looking for here is not a between search because the beginning and end are unknown.
So is this a postgresql limitation or is there something other than manipulating the cost of a table scan to something silly that I can use to convince the query planner to use the index?

I am using PostgreSQL 9.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
ORDER BY lower(title) DESC
```

or

```
ORDER BY lower(title)
```

to *match* your functional index, so it can be utilized.
`ORDER BY` is irrelevant for the *selection* of rows in the other two queries. That's why the index can be used in those cases.

Comment: My word, it's so obvious when you look at it. Thanks!